# Does calling Select New result in the underlying query being executed?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

If you append .ToList() to a query, it results in the query executing against the database.  If you use `Select New` does this immediately execute the query, as well, or does it still allow the query to be changed before execution?

---

If needed, here is an example:

```
var query = db.Cars();

if(model.CarNameSearch != "")
   query = query.where(u => u.CarName == model.CarNameSearch);

return query.ToList();
```

In the above example, the query doesn't actually execute against the database until .ToList() is called.

If instead I do this, does Select New result in the query executing before the return:

```
var query = from cars in db.Cars
            select New MyResult{
                 MyModelCarName = cars.CarName,
                 MyModelCarColor= cars.Color
            };

if(model.CarNameSearch != "")
   query = query.where(u => u.MyModelCarName == model.CarNameSearch);

return query.ToList();
```

Comment: There is no `Select New` but instead in Linq C# we have the select keyword which is used in your example as keyword query syntax and the new keyword is used to create an object.

Comment: Plus, there is no `where` method. Uppercase it to `Where`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `new` or not doesn't matter here. It's the LINQ method. The query syntax `from - select` is `Select()` under the covers and this is [one of the methods with deferred execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/classification-of-standard-query-operators-by-manner-of-execution).

So the second code fragment is a perfectly valid way to compose a query expression with deferred execution that will execute no sooner than `ToList`.